# Controlling ports in a loop using Vex RobotC

Tags: c, for-loop, ioports, robotc

I am using `Vex` `RobotC` and have a function: `setTouchLEDRGB(portx, R,G,B);` which sets the RGB colour of a touch LED.

I have 9 TouchLEDs and want to change the colour of them all at once, now annoyingly this is 9 lines of code at a time, i hope to create a function with an iteration such as:

```
for (int i = 0, i < 9, i++)
{
    setTouchLEDRGB(port[i], R, G, B);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Indexing starts with `0` in C.

Comment: @pzaenger while you are generally right and most likely are hinting a bug the OP has in his code, the port array in question might in fact have ANY offset - maybe even 1 :)

Comment: @Till That's a good point. But well, I guess it is fine to let him know in case he/she doesn't know. Actually it should be `i < 9` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTouchLEDRGB(portx, R,G,B);
```

Not sure about the platform, but you could create an array containg the ports:

```
#define NUM_PORTS 9

// 'int' should be the type of your port parameter
int ports[NUM_PORTS] = {PORTA, PORTB, etc};

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PORTS; ++i) {
    setTouchLEDRGB(ports[i], R, G, B);
}
```

Comment: How about avoiding the preprocessor and using a static const int for the number of ports?

Comment: @Till - Not sure if those would take any space on the OP's platform, but could be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have variable or macros for the ports called portn

```
   int ports[9];
    ports[0] = port0;
    ports[1] = port1;
    ...

    for (i = 0, i <9, i ++)
    {
     setTouchLEDRGB(ports[i], R, G, B);
    }
```